# macro for mutt to mark the whole folder as read

Tags: email, mutt

I have too much mails in some folders managed by sieve. Is there the macro which allows you to just mark the folder as read, rather than just put **O** key signature on each separate mail?

Comment: Have you tried using tags?

Answer (score 6):

Mark unread messages, then toggle the unread flag on marked messages.

```
T ~O | ~N
;N
```

You can put this in a macro if you want.

```
macro index <f42> "T ~O | ~N\n;N"
```